# How to find the top 5 values in an aggregate function

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm trying to output the top 5 values of SUM(t.shares) and I also need to display company name, current stock price and percentage of the last price change. When I add sp.price in select I have to add it into group by as well then the table returns way too many unwanted rows. Is there a way that I can work around it? Also, how do I calculate the percentage change for the last price change?

[Here is the ERD](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OTHgx.jpg)

Here is the question:

List the top 5 companies (in terms of shareholder trade volume)
on the New York Stock Exchange.  Display the company name, shareholder trade volume,
the current price and the percentage change for the last price change. Sort the output
in descending order of trade volume.  The sample data in the database contains information
for only 3 companies but your query must continue to list only the top 5 companies even when
there is data for more companies.

```
select
    c.name,
    SUM(t.shares)
from trade t
    join company c
        on t.stock_id = c.stock_id
    join stock_exchange se
        on se.stock_ex_id = t.stock_ex_id
    join stock_price sp
        on sp.stock_ex_id = se.stock_ex_id 
        and sp.stock_id = c.stock_id
    where se.name = 'New York Stock Exchange'
group by c.name;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can apply a window function to the result of the aggregate and use that to filter the overall result:

```
select name, shares
from (
  select c.name,
         SUM(t.shares) as shares,
         dense_rank() over (order by SUM(t.shares) desc) as rnk
  from trade t
    join company c
        on t.stock_id = c.stock_id
    join stock_exchange se
        on se.stock_ex_id = t.stock_ex_id
    join stock_price sp
        on sp.stock_ex_id = se.stock_ex_id 
        and sp.stock_id = c.stock_id
  where se.name = 'New York Stock Exchange'
  group by c.name
) 
where rnk <= 5  
order by shares desc;
```

Answer (score 0):

I belive what you need is Analytic Funtion instead of Agreggate function

here you can get the idea:

'11g':

```
SELECT * FROM (
SELECT * FROM (
select
    c.*,
    SUM(t.shares) over (PARTITION BY c.name) as Total_SUM
from trade t
    join company c
        on t.stock_id = c.stock_id
    join stock_exchange se
        on se.stock_ex_id = t.stock_ex_id
    join stock_price sp
        on sp.stock_ex_id = se.stock_ex_id 
        and sp.stock_id = c.stock_id
    where se.name = 'New York Stock Exchange'
            ) ORDER BY Total_SUM DESC
            ) WHERE ROWNUMBER <=5;
```

'>= 12c':

```
SELECT * FROM (
select
    c.*,
    SUM(t.shares) over (PARTITION BY c.name) as Total_SUM
from trade t
    join company c
        on t.stock_id = c.stock_id
    join stock_exchange se
        on se.stock_ex_id = t.stock_ex_id
    join stock_price sp
        on sp.stock_ex_id = se.stock_ex_id 
        and sp.stock_id = c.stock_id
    where se.name = 'New York Stock Exchange'
            ) ORDER BY Total_SUM DESC FETCH FIRST 5 ROWS ONLY
```